# How RowMapper can be an Anonymous Class

Tags: java, spring

I was reading through Spring in Action and found something like this could anyone explain how we have used RowMapper as an Anonymous class if it is an Interface as per [RowMapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html) documentation.

```
 public Employee getEmployeeById(long id) {
      return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
          "select id, firstname, lastname, salary " +
          "from employee where id=?",
          new RowMapper<Employee>() {
            public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs,
                    int rowNum) throws SQLException {
              Employee employee = new Employee();
              employee.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
              employee.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));

              employee.setLastName(rs.getString("lastname"));
              employee.setSalary(rs.getBigDecimal("salary"));
              return employee;
            }
          },
          id);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anonymous class `new Something() {...}` is not an instance of `Something`. Instead, it's a *subclass/implementation* of `Something`. And so, it's perfectly valid and useful to derive anonymous classes from interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

[Anonymous](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) class are not instance of a class but just another way to define a class, something similar to a nested class, but less reusable since it's method related. 
Since you can define class that implements interfaces

```
public A implements B {

}
```

and you can reference the instance of that class, declaring as an interface

```
B b = new A();
```

you can do it also with anonymous class.
The only thing to do and to remember (for this exist the compiler), is that you have to implements all method defined in the interface itself.

That solution, is a more concise way to do this:

```
public EmployeeController {

     public Employee getEmployeeById(long id) {
          return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
              "select id, firstname, lastname, salary " +
              "from employee where id=?",
              new CustomRowMapper(),
              id);
        }


   class CustomRowMapper implements RowMapper<Employee>() {
            public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
              Employee employee = new Employee();
              employee.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
              employee.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));

              employee.setLastName(rs.getString("lastname"));
              employee.setSalary(rs.getBigDecimal("salary"));
              return employee;
            }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax

```
new SomeInterface() {
  // Definition for abstract methods
}
```

defines an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). As long as all methods specified in the interface are defined within the braces, this is a valid class which implements the given interface.

Note that this expression defines an anonymous class implicitly *and* an instance of that class.